# Profile doesn't match Application Identifier com.domainname.helloworld

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, provisioning-profile

I try to run a HelloWorld project into my client device, the application identifier in Xcode is: `com.domainname.HelloWorld`, and when i created the provisioning profile, in the AppID, i have putted: `com.domainname.helloworld` (lower case).

Now, in Xcode, i try to assign the code signing identity to the provisioning profile i have created, however, in the drop list, i can see the provisioning profile but i can't select it.

[image]

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.oogtech.org/content/tag/provisioning-profile/)  and i have doubt i didn't knew how to `Don’t forget to add the new provisioning profile to XCode as well.`

Can you please help me there? thanx in advance.

Comment: Did you change Bundle identifier into plist to com.domainname.HelloWorld?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BundleIds are case-sensitive.

Make sure you call it `com.domainname.HelloWorld` in your Info.plist.

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/OSXWorkflowGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html):

> Typically, the bundle ID in your Xcode project is a string formatted
>   as a reverse-domain name such as com.MyCompany.MyProductName, where
>   you replace MyCompanyName and MyProductName with your domain and
>   product name. However, unlike domain names, **app IDs and bundle IDs are
>   case sensitive**.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with  my application Extinct Birds, Xcode adds disabled suffix with project name  in Application Target->Bundle Identifier
Way to find this in your project Info.plist is by searching for  CFBundleIdentifier
You may get the following text entry form the file

CFBundleIdentifier
    com.softwebsys.ExtinctBirds${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}

For me removing ${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier} from the string worked well. Here is my final  entry
CFBundleIdentifier
    com.softwebsys.ExtinctBirds